# Angular: Convert 2D json object to XML

Tags: json, angular, xml

I'm using the following code to convert a 2D array to json and from json to XML:

```js
export class Son
{
    public d : number;
    public e : number[][];
    constructor (){
        this.e = new Array (16);
        for (let i=0;i<16;i++)
            this.e[i] = new Array(2);
    }
}

export class Father
{
    public a : number;
    public b : number;
    public c : Son;
    constructor (){
        this.c = new Son();
    }
}
var xml2js = require('xml2js');
    var builder = new xml2js.Builder();

    var a_obj = new Father();
    a_obj.a=1;
    a_obj.b=2;
    a_obj.c.d=3;
    a_obj.c.e[0][0]=1;
    a_obj.c.e[0][1]=1;

    var a_json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a_obj));
    var a_xml = builder.buildObject(a_json);
```

If the object (a_obj) does not contain 2D array, it works fine. 
But in my case I got the following xml string:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
  <c>
    <e/>
    <e/>
    <e/>
    <e/>
    <e/>
    <e/>
    <e/>
    <e/>
    <e/>
    <e/>
    <e/>
    <e/>
    <e/>
    <e/>
    <e/>
    <e/>
    <d>3</d>
  </c>
  <a>1</a>
  <b>2</b>
</root>
```

Thank you in advance for your reply.
Zvika

Answer (score 0):

How do you like this function:

```js
function object2Xml(obj, tag='xml', attributes={}) {
    var inner = '';
    if (typeof (obj) === 'string') {
        inner = obj;
    } else if (typeof (obj) === 'number') {
        inner = obj;
    } else if (typeof (obj) === 'boolean') {
        inner = obj;
    } else if (typeof (obj) === 'function') {
        return '';
    } else if (typeof (obj) === 'object') {
        if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
            return obj.map((v)=>object2Xml(v, tag, {array: true})).join('')
        } else {
            if (tag==='xml' && obj.constructor.name!=='Object') {
                tag = obj.constructor.name
            }
            Object.keys(obj).forEach(key=>{
                inner += object2Xml(obj[key], key)
            });
        }
    }

    var attr = '';
    Object.keys(attributes).forEach(key=>{
        attr += ' '+key + '=' + '"'+attributes[key]+'"';
    });

    return '<' + tag + attr + '>' + inner + '</' + tag + '>'
}
```

you can use it like `object2Xml(a_obj);`.

you know, there is not one way to transform objects into xml, there are many decisions to make, if a property in js should become an attribute or a string value, if an array get wrapped into an extra  tag,... But the function above might give you a starting point.

Comment: Hi Tobias. Thank you very much.